# ExpressCard SSD Boot on Laptop

Tags: laptop, boot, ssd, bios, expresscard

Is it possible to boot from an ExpressCard SSD? If so, what are the constraints?

I am interested in trying to set up my computer like I do for my servers which is install base OS is on a small read-centric drive like an internal USB and use the hard drives in a RAID array. Since my laptop does not have internal USB, I was thinking that an ExpressCard SSD would fit the bill. Then I can use the other two hard drive's as a RAIDZ array and thus get server quality resilience and performance on a my laptop.

I am currently using an HP EliteBook 8760w. If HP's cannot do this OOTB, is there a way to hack in a custom BIOS? Maybe there are other laptop brands that can do this?

I don't see why we cannot have this great server model used on our laptops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read you can but not if it is using the USB interface as it refreshes on boot up.

I am currently on a laptop that is booted from an external drive, I pinched the internal HDD connector and shorted it out. Luckily for me I have a powered ESATA port and can boot from that.